# How to compare today date with date in database with php

Tags: php, sql

Please help on how to compare a date with date in database in php

something like

```
$today = date("y-m-d");
select * from table name where date <= $today
```

It is not working this way

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date <= CURDATE()
```

You can also use

```
SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME()
```

will result in something like this:

```
NOW() --> 2014-11-22 12:45:34
CURDATE() --> 2014-11-22
CURTIME() --> 12:45:34
```

For more information go to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp)

Comment: Thanks, i already have date in the database, i want where date is less than or equal to current date in the database, what i simple want to code is an expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes:

```
$sql = "select * from table name where date <= '{$today}';
```

And field `date` in database set as `datetime`